# CVCalendar iOS Control - Select Multiple Dates

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the CVCalendar control from Github [CVCalendar Repo](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar). I 'd like to be able to select multiple dates on a single control. Based on my search till now it seems that the CVCalendar control allows only a single date selection.

Is that true? Does anyone knows if it is possible to implement this functionality using CVCalendar?

Any other suggestion or workaround is more than welcomed.